# Set Value of Cell in Workbook A as Sum of Values of Range in Workbook B

Tags: excel

Runtime Error 1004
Method Range of Object _ Global failed.

```
Workbooks("Deep Dive_Unadjusted_Group_Sept 20191025_Template.xlsm").Worksheets("ID").Cells(42, 14).Value = Workbooks.Open("MRP_ID_September_20191015.xlsx").Worksheets("Pnl HF + GF").sumrange(Range("L51:53"))
```

Please assist where did it go wrong.
I have no IT/Code background. Just learning VBA by myself to optimise work in Excel.

Comment: What is `sumrange` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This -

```
"L51:53"
```

is not a valid range - did you mean "L51:L53" or ?

Also `sumrange` is not a worksheet method.

This might be what you want:

```
  Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook

  Set wb = Workbooks("Deep Dive_Unadjusted_Group_Sept 20191025_Template.xlsm")
  Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("MRP_ID_September_20191015.xlsx")

  wb.Worksheets("ID").Cells(42, 14).Value = _
            Application.Sum(wb2.Worksheets("Pnl HF + GF").Range("L51:53"))
```

Comment: Sorry have added L. But now its runtime error 438 instead.

Comment: What is the text of the error?  `sumrange` isn't a worksheet method, so that looks wrong...

Comment: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: I would like to populate a cell value in workbook A using:a sum of a range of values in workbook B